# Unable to save data in database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

I am using the following code to save data in PHP. The data I want to save is:

```
Latitudes:"[47.99267886541119,47.81223227508317]"

Longitudes:"[19.403228759765625,19.015960693359375]"
```

Please help me rectify any error in the code.

```
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$con)
{
 echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}
 if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'test'))
{
  echo 'Database Not Selected';
  }
  for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['Latitudes']);$i=$i+1)
  {
  $Latitude = $_POST['Latitudes'][$i];
   }
    for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['Longitudes']);$i=$i+1)
   {
    $Longitude= $_POST['Longitudes'][$i];
   }
   $sql = "insert into polyline (lat,lng) values 
      ('$Latitude','$Longitude')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
   echo 'Not Inserted';
  }

 else
  {
    echo 'Inserted Successfully';
  }

   header("refresh:100; url=Final edited copy.html");


  ?>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
var polyOptions = {
    geodesic: true,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    }
    var poly=new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
    poly.setMap(map);
    var evtListnr = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event){
    var path = poly.getPath();
     if (poly.getPath().getLength() == 1) {
  google.maps.event.removeListener(evtListnr);
}
    path.push(event.latLng);
    var coordinates_poly=poly.getPath().getArray();
    var lat_poly = [];
    var lng_poly = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <coordinates_poly.length; i++){
    lat_poly.push(coordinates_poly[i].lat());
    lng_poly.push(coordinates_poly[i].lng());
    }
    var str_lat_poly=JSON.stringify(lat_poly);
    var str_lng_poly=JSON.stringify(lng_poly);
    document.getElementById("data1").value= 'Latitudes:"'+str_lat_poly+'"';
    document.getElementById("data2").value= 'Longitudes:"'+str_lng_poly+'"';
    });
    }
</script>
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<br/><input name="Latitudes" type="text" id="data1" size="100" value='' readonly/><br/>
<br/><input name="Longitudes" type="text" id="data2" size="100" value='' readonly/><br/>
<input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: post the errors first and the html for this

Comment: [mysqli's error reporting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) may be of better use than echoing your own failure strings.

Comment: The html code has been pasted as well. Message is still "Not inserted". @Fred-ii-

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are reseting $Latitude and $Longitude values each time your loop iterates. You should use:

```
$Latitude .= $_POST['Latitudes'][$i]; // And some logic to add comma till last value is reached.
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

The POST values (i.e. `$_POST['Longitudes']` and `$_POST['Latitudes']` are strings, not arrays.

See proof of this in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/by3k-jie0).

#### Solutions

There are various ways this could be handled - some examples include:

- using 2 (or more) text inputs (i.e. `<input>` tags) with attributes that support array syntax (refer to the [PHP.net HTML FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) for more info):

  ```
  <input name="Latitudes[]" type="text" id="lat1" size="100" value='' readonly/>
  <input name="Latitudes[]" type="text" id="lat2" size="100" value='' readonly/>
  ```
- parsing those strings - e.g. with regular expressions (can be cumbersome)